# GROUP BY function cancels DISTINCT

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, distinct

I have an SQL query that joins several tables that produces duplicates on two of the rows. I use the `DISTINCT` keyword to eliminate duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          o.day as day,
          g.id AS id,
          g.name AS name,
          o.num AS num,
          o.version as version
        FROM
          table_one o
          INNER JOIN table_two t ON
            o.ID = t.ID
          INNER JOIN table_three g ON
            t.ID = g.ID
          INNER JOIN table_four gs ON
            g.ID = gs.ID
            AND
          INNER JOIN table_five s ON
            gs.ID = s.ID
          INNER JOIN table_six z ON
            s.ID = z.ID
          INNER JOIN table_seven bg ON
            bg.ID = g.ID;
```

This returns the two rows like I would want, that otherwise I would see duplicates if I did not use `DISTINCT`:

```
1/2/19, 5, first, 25, 1
1/5/19, 7, second, 20, 1
```

If I remove `DISTINCT`, then the two rows are duplicated, giving me four rows:

```
1/2/19, 5, first, 25, 1
1/2/19, 5, first, 25, 1
1/5/19, 7, second, 20, 1
1/5/19, 7, second, 20, 1
```

So my end goal is to use a `GROUP BY` function so that I can add up my `o.num` field and group them by the rest of the fields. If I add a `GROUP BY` function to the above query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
          o.day as day,
          g.id AS id,
          g.name AS name,
          SUM(o.num) AS num,
          o.version as version
        FROM
          table_one o
          INNER JOIN table_two t ON
            o.ID = t.ID
          INNER JOIN table_three g ON
            t.ID = g.ID
          INNER JOIN table_four gs ON
            g.ID = gs.ID
            AND
          INNER JOIN table_five s ON
            gs.ID = s.ID
          INNER JOIN table_six z ON
            s.ID = z.ID
          INNER JOIN table_seven bg ON
            bg.ID = g.ID
        GROUP BY
          o.day as day,
          g.id AS id,
          g.name AS name,
          o.version as version;
```

I get two rows back, but the `o.num` amount is doubled (essentially performing  `GROUP BY` without `DISTINCT`:

```
1/2/19, 5, first, 50, 1
1/5/19, 7, second, 40, 1
```

NOTE: You may be wondering why I'm trying to use a `GROUP BY` when I get the results I want with the first query. I only included the rows that are being duplicated. For some reason all other rows aren't seeing this behavior. Is there a way I can get `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` to work together?

Comment: well….yes, you are grouping the original data set, and using sum over the duplicated values

Comment: @Lamak yes so my question is how to fix that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to remove duplicates and then sum values, insert your query into subquery.

```
select day, id, name, sum(num) num, version
from (
  -- your query here with DISTINCT clause 
)
group by day, id, name, version
```

If you get duplicates, there may be some issues with join conditions. For me is't difficult to judge, don't know datasets.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `SUM(DISTINCT o.num)`:

```
SELECT o.day as day,
       g.id AS id,
       g.name AS name,
       SUM(DISTINCT o.num) AS num,
       o.version as version
FROM table_one o
INNER JOIN table_two t ON o.ID = t.ID
INNER JOIN table_three g ON t.ID = g.ID
INNER JOIN table_four gs ON g.ID = gs.ID
INNER JOIN table_five s ON gs.ID = s.ID
INNER JOIN table_six z ON s.ID = z.ID
INNER JOIN table_seven bg ON bg.ID = g.ID
GROUP BY o.day as day,
         g.id AS id,
         g.name AS name,
         o.version as version;
```